# Importing and running Django development server

Tags: python, django

An application that uses Flask framework, can start the built-in werkzeug development server simply by calling `app.run()` :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run()
```

Consider an empty Django project "myproject" created as follows: `django-admin.py startproject myproject`. Is there a non-hackish way to start Django's development server for `myproject` as it's done in Flask? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `management.call_command()` to emulate what `manage.py` does:

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('runserver')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I've been looking for. P.S. will be able to accept your answer in six minutes :)